# Can I marry my dead wife's (widowed) sister?

Tags: nikah

I am 37 years of age. My wife has passed away, and her younger sister is widow since the last 1 year.

Our families have started a discussion to get her in Nikah. Both of us, have kids.

So they think its better for me to marry her so that the kids stay within our family. But I am confused if this is halal or haram.

Answer (score 1):

it is halal to marry your wife sister if you are not married to her sister anymore (in your case she has died) on one condition that your wife sister has finished her adh